# CMD.exe command in java not terminating

Tags: java, cmd, terminate

I'm trying to use cmd.exe to search for a file in a specific directory and then display the path in a java program and write it to a file.  The problem is that the process never terminates.

Here is my code:

```
String[] str = new String[] { "cmd.exe ", "cd c:\\",
                        " dir /b /s documents", "2>&1" };

            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try{

                Process p = rt.exec(str);
                InputStream is =p.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(is);


                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(in);
                String line = buff.readLine();
                while( line != null )
                {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                    line = buff.readLine();
                }
                System.out.println( sb );
                File f = new File("test.txt");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fos.write(sb.toString().getBytes());
                fos.close();

            }catch( Exception ex )
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
cmd /c
```

instead of simply

```
cmd
```

[Reference](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: I should put the cmd /c instead of cmd.exe as a command in str? If so, I tried that and got an IOException - The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: You have to put `/c` in a separate parameter. Runtime.exec( "cmd.exe", "/c", ... )

Comment: cmd.exe with the parameter /c so your code reads: `String[] str = new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", "\"cd c:\\&&dir /b /s documents\"" };` Whether or not this works I can't tell, but that would be what tangens meant :) Please note that multiple commands needs to be seperated by `&&` and enclosed in "".

Comment: Thank you tangens - I added /c as one of the parameters like TommyA said.  The program terminated, but for some reason, now the StringBuffer is not finding the results.

Answer (score 1):

`Runtime.exec` doesn't work that way.  You can't pass multiple commands like that to cmd.exe.

`Runtime.exec` allows you to execute a single process with a list of arguments.  It does not provide any "shell" operations (like `2>&1` for instance).  You must do that sort of IO redirection yourself using the Input/Output streams.

It's similar to calling another program's `main` function.

You could try `Runtime.exec( new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", "dir", "C:\\" } );

But realistically, if you want file listings, you're much better off using the facilities in the `java.io.File` class, which won't depend on operating system specific features.

Answer (score 0):

why are not using [Java to do directory traversal](http://tinyurl.com/y928y6e) instead of calling external shell command? It makes your code not portable!

Answer (score 0):

You must use the start command in addition to the cmd.exe process with the /C or /K switch BEFORE the start command. Example: to convert the Windows's command interpreter in a bash console (from the mingw prroject) you must invoke the exec method of the Runtime class with the command "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C start C:\mingw\msys\1.0\bin\bash.exe" (I use an external command rather than an internal because it's more signifiant but you can use internal command like DIR and so on).